# How can I record automated outgoing emails in Activity Section against an Opportunity triggered by record-triggered flows?

Tags: email, visual-workflow

In my Salesforce implementation, I have set up several record-triggered flows on Opportunities that send  emails using Email Alerts. I need to ensure that these outgoing emails are recorded as Activity records against the corresponding Opportunity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Summer '23 release, this can now be done out of the box. For that you can use the **Send Email Action** in Flows that now includes the ability to save the email as an activity against a record.

Here's how to do this:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_builder_log_emails_sent_using_the_flow_builder_send_email_action.htm&release=244&type=5